# Creating Android apps without Java

Tags: android, scala, programming-languages, clojure

I'd like to start creating Android apps but I don't like Java. I read that scala can be used to do it. Are there another option?(Clojure?)

I'm a Python/Django developer so it would be great to learn a pretty different language.

Comment: C# with MonoDroid is an upcoming choice. Still in beta though, last I checked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At this point Scala is the one that is most mature..I wanted to try groovy myself but its not even out of alpha..

Plus Scala on android has docs..:)

Comment: http://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin <- I recommend this if you wonder how you might start developing scala for android. It requires simple-build-tool, it provides you with a solution to compile, test, proguard-optimize and install (in the emulator or device) android applications with scala or java. Even automatically on code change (~install-emulator).

Answer (score 5):

It's not hard to do with [Mirah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirah_%28programming_language%29) (formerly Duby), a very young language based on Ruby that compiles to bytecode that's basically indistinguishable from Java's, but adds some great new features like closures, type inference, and obviously a Ruby-like syntax. It's particularly well-suited for Android because it has no runtime or standard library (it uses compiler plugins instead) outside the JDK, whereas basically all other JVM languages bring along a lot of baggage, especially languages that weren't designed to target the JVM (like Ruby and Python).

http://github.com/technomancy/Garrett

Much nicer than writing Java!

Answer (score 4):

for clojure development a useful tutorial: http://riddell.us/ClojureAndAndroidWithEmacsOnUbuntu.html

Clojure gets a LOT of benefit from android-2.2's JIT compiler and has not really been widely adopted on previous versions.

Answer (score 3):

[Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/) is an awesome environment for using web-ish skills (like HTML, CSS, and JavaScript) to build native apps for Android (and iPhone, and desktops, etc.). For example, [the gang at Intridea have made several popular Android & iPhone apps with Titanium Mobile](http://intridea.com/tag/iphone), including the [OilReporter app](http://oilreporter.org/) that has been used for gathering data on the extent of the Gulf oil spill.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Python, maybe [SL4A (Scripting Layer for Android)](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) is a good choice.

You could write python script that runs on Android and use Android API, but it also has a drawback that you need install Python/SL4A runtime library on your Android device.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other solutions listed here previously, you have:

- PhoneGap
- Rhodes
- AIR (pre-release)
- AppInventor
- Clojure

Answer (score 1):

Another immature implementation is JRuby/Ruboto: http://blog.danieljackoway.com/first-ruboto-release.html